# Instragram - Redirect URI dose not match with registered - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios7, instagram

I am getting error while Login with oAuth for Instagram, it says the `redirectURI` is wrong. I have researched on it and I have checked many answers on stackoverflow but its not helpful for me.

Here is the complete detail of what I did in my application.

1) I set my ClientId in pList for redirect URI :
[image]

2) I have added ig and authorize while creating the URI:

[image]

3)Now, I set ClientID in Instragram API :
[image]

And Here is my RedirectURI :

https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&redirect_uri=igdd5fb08a33444af0b2b9c9420e69bc35%3A%2F%2Fauthorize&scope=relationships&client_id=dd5fb08a33444af0b2b9c9420e69bc35

When I fire the URl after login, it gives me the following error:

[image]

Can anyone help to find out where I am going wrong ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The redirect URI you're providing is not what you have defined in your client settings.

1) Go to http://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/

2) For your desired client/application, look for `REDIRECT URI`.

[image]

3) Make sure you provide the same redirect uri in your request as it is defined in your client/application settings. In your case, `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?response_type=token&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&client_id=CLIENT-ID`

Note: You may provide an optional scope parameter to request additional permissions outside of the “basic” permissions scope.

Note: You may provide an optional state parameter to carry through any server-specific state you need to, for example, protect against CSRF issues.

At this point, we present the user with a login screen and then a confirmation screen where they approve your app’s access to his/her Instagram data.

4) Once a user successfully authenticates and authorizes your application, instagram will redirect the user to your redirect_uri with a code parameter that you’ll use to request the access_token like `http://your-redirect-uri?code=CODE`.

For more information to learn about authentication process [[Link]](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/)

**tl;dr. The Redirect URI you send to `/authorized` must be same as the registered URI in your app.**